# Paste into Xterm on MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, copy-paste

I'm running Xterm in a Linux VMware Virtual Machine. I can copy out of it but I can't figure out how to paste into it. On a desktop computer, the middle mouse button or shift + insert does the trick. How about on a MacBook Air?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an external mouse, clicking both buttons (if it's a two button mouse) should do it.

I'm not aware of a way to do it with the trackpad only unless you use a third party tool like [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) which will let you bind, eg, <kbd>⌥</kbd> + left click to a middle click. I've just tested exactly that combination and it works fine for pasting into an X11.app Xterm so should work fine with your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Most terminals on Linux allow you to paste with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

(The shift is to make this match <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for Copy, because you can't use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in a terminal because that's already mapped to kill the running process [^C].)